# Which arguments should be used when calling a sub with parameters (ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba, object, arguments, subroutine

I'm making a macro on VBA that is attached to a data validation list in excel. When a certain option is selected from the list I want it to run a macro assigned to that selection. However I am repeatedly getting the error 'Compile error. Argument is not optional.' I understand I need to add parameters after calling the macro but anything I enter results in 'Object required' or 'expected )'

This code is in my worksheet. The line 'Case "Fifteen": Macro1' is the one with the error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P4")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("P4")
    Case "Fifteen": Macro1
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

The following code is located in a module - It is used to copy values from the cells in one worksheet to another.

```
Sub Macro1(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Sheets("Calculator").Range("C18:D19")
Set r2 = Sheets("Answers").Range("I14:J15")
If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
         r2.Value = r1.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any idea's what the Argument parameters should be? I thought it would be along the lines of Case "Fifteen":Macro1("C18:D19") or Case "Fifteen":Macro1(r1), but no luck was had.

The code in the module works when it is on its own so I don't think there would be any issues with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I looked around and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: You need to pass a Range to the function. Try `Case "Fifteen": Macro1(Range("P4"))`

Comment: Cell `P4` will never be within the range of `r1` in your `Macro1` code, and other than that `Target` is never used within `Macro1`.  So don't have that argument because it's not used.  Change the Sub to just be `Sub Macro1()` and remove the `If Intersect...` line

Comment: you are not passing the Target, pass the Target again, understand it is a local copy to the sub but: Macro1 (Target)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. By removing the `intersect` lines it now works as intended. The final code is below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Select Case Range("P4")
        Case "Fifteen": Macro1
        End Select
    End If
    End Sub

Sub Macro1()

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Sheets("Calculator").Range("C18:D19")
Set r2 = Sheets("Answers").Range("I14:J15")
      Application.EnableEvents = False
         r2.Value = r1.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```